# Toggle selectable, enable in viewport

Tags: scripting

I wrote a small script that should:

1. unhide
2. enable in viewport
3. enable in render
4. enable selectable

for ALL objects in the scene

> ```
> import bpy
> from bpy import context
> from bpy import data
>
> # all objects
> all_objects = data.objects
>
> for ob in data.objects:
>     ob.select_set(True)
>     ob.hide_set(False)
>     ob.hide_render = False
>     ob.hide_select = False
> ```

However it wont toggle everything on, there are still objects or collections turned off.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Is it perhaps not selecting everything with data.objects? Maybe i'm misunderstanding it.

Update:

I updated my script to include collections but it gives me an error

> ```
> import bpy
> from bpy import context
> from bpy import data
>
> for collection in bpy.data.collections:
>     collections.hide_viewport = False
>    
>     for obj in collection.all_objects:
>        obj.select_set(True)
>        obj.hide_set(False)
>        obj.hide_render = False
>        obj.hide_select = False
> ```

Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'hide_viewport'

Comment: It is not selecting the nested collections.  You need to iterate over scene collections as well.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks, ive updated my initial message with an updated script but its giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not all collection properties are in collection itself. *hide_viewport* for example depends on view layer, so it located in the view layer. You can find it like this (for the first collection):

```
 bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[0].hide_viewport
 bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[0].exclude
```

For nested list like this, you have to write recursion, there is no complite list of it

Comment: Sorry, this goes way above my head.  I think I understand it partially because there is the [scenes] and the [view layer] so i would have to iterate over both layers? Could I perhaps get an ELI5?